# value not getting stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a form where it asks user to upload his/her photo. But i am not able to save encoded value of my image. I want to save this value in a variable. I am not getting why my value is not getting saved in 'result' variable.

```
 <html>
<body>
<input type="file" id="inp"/>
<img id="img" />
<div id="b64"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function EL(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } 

function readFile() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var FR= new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
      EL("img").src       = e.target.result;
      EL("b64").innerHTML = e.target.result;
    };       
   var result = FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    console.log(result);
  }
}

EL("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because it's an asynchronous process. You need to get your result inside your `onload` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because event `onload` runs asynchronously, and you try to access the value synchronously, which result to `undefined`

move your logic inside `onload`, or if you want synchronous code style use `promises` instead.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" id="inp"/>
<img id="img" />
<div id="b64"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function EL(id) { return document.getElementById(id); } 

function readFile() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var FR= new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
      EL("img").src       = e.target.result;
      EL("b64").innerHTML = e.target.result;

      //put your code here
      console.log(e.target.result);

    };       
    FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
  }
}

EL("inp").addEventListener("change", readFile, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```